# How to understand the following Bayesian schema?

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

My knowledge of probability is basic, and I understand the point of Bayesian interpretation most roughly. The following is part of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250178883_Uniqueness_Revisited). It is about how p can be rational for person 1 and not-p can be rational for person 2 even when they share all their evidence. So the case is about two detectives and two body of evidence Q and R. one detective has Q, the other has R. Q supports p and R equally supports not-p. Now when they share their evidence with one another, how can Q+R supports p?

In particular, in the following scheme I don't understand where n came from, and when the numbers 2 and 4 came from.

> Now, as it happens, the only plausible non-categorical notion of
>   evidence around is the Bayesian one, according to which, recall, Q is
>   evidence for P iff P is more probable conditional on Q than it is on
>   its own, that is, iff Pr(P | Q) > Pr(P ). The natural way to extend
>   this definition to one of strong evidential support is to add to it
>   the requirement that Pr(P | Q) be high, where “high” needs to be
>   filled in (though, patently, we will not want it to mean that Pr(P |
>   Q) = 1; surely Q can be strong evidence for P if it fails to make P
>   entirely certain).22 To appreciate, then, why Goldman’s negative
>   verdict on whether the detectives in the example can rationally stick
>   to their beliefs after sharing their evidence is not nearly as
>   obviously correct as his wording—“Surely not”—makes it appear,23
>   consider the class of probability models defined by the following
>   schema (n ∈ N+):

```
P   Q   R   Pr                      P   Q   R   Pr

T   T   T   1/(2n + 4)              F   T   T   0
T   T   F   n/(2n + 4)              F   T   F   1/(2n + 4)
T   F   T   0                       F   F   T   (n + 1)/(2n + 4)
T   F   F   1                       F   F   F   0
```

> As is easy to check, on each model satisfying this schema it holds
>   that (i) Pr(P | Q) = (n + 1)/(n + 2) > (n + 2)/(2n + 4) = Pr(P ); (ii)
>   Pr(¬P | R) = (n + 1)/(n + 2) > (n + 2)/(2n + 4) = Pr(¬P ); and (iii)
>   Pr(P | Q ∧ R) = 1 > (n + 2)/(2n + 4) = Pr(P ). So, by taking n
>   sufficiently large, we have on any acceptable reading of “high” in the
>   definition of “strong evidential support” that Q is strong evidence
>   for P, R is strong evidence for ¬P, yet the conjunction of Q and R is
>   again strong evidence for P. Furthermore, it is easy to see that, on
>   its own, Q is equally strong evidence for P as R, also on its own, is
>   evidence for ¬P (and thus against P). It follows that one detective
>   may have what in the eyes of both of them is strong evidence
>   incriminating Lefty, the other what is also in the eyes of both
>   (equally) strong evidence incriminating Righty, yet after pooling
>   their evidence the former detective has become even more confident—in
>   fact, subjectively certain—that Lefty committed the crime while the
>   latter has become more confident—subjectively certain—that Righty is
>   the perpetrator. If this is not immediately clear, just use the above
>   schema to (partially) define the detectives’ degrees-of-belief
>   functions by choosing an appropriate value for n and making the
>   following substitutions: for one detective’s degrees-of-belief
>   function, substitute “Lefty committed the crime” for P, the
>   house-maiden’s testimony for Q, and the gardener’s testimony for R;
>   for the other detective’s degrees-of-belief function, substitute
>   “Righty committed the crime” for P, the gardener’s testimony for Q,
>   and the house-maiden’s testimony for R. It hence appears that the
>   mechanical principle that equal but opposing forces cancel out has no
>   analogue in the only formally precise theory of evidence we presently
>   have.